# What does it mean for an orbit to "accumulate"?

Tags: group-theory, definition

For example, from Beardon's "A Primer On Riemann Surfaces",

> ...Show that g is a homeomorphism of D onto itself, and that no orbit accumulates in D.

I'm simply looking for a definition of the word accumulates; I haven't encountered it yet and he presents no formal meaning previously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very roughly, it is saying something like that the orbit should not have a subsequence with a [Limit Point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_point).  That wiki page contains various definitions related to  accumulation points in a topological space.  The specific one given is:

```
"A point x ∈ X is a cluster point or accumulation point of a sequence
(xn)n ∈ N if, for every neighbourhood V of x, there are infinitely many 
natural numbers n such that xn ∈ V."
```